# Wi-Fi connection periodically dies after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-10-upgrade, wifi-configuration

I have an Asus X550L laptop, and just upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1.

Since the upgrade, my Wi-Fi connection is acting weird. Basically it's working fine when I turn on my computer, then a few hours later it will die for no apparent reason. At this point, when I try to connect manually to the Wi-Fi, it will say "Cannot connect to this network". I usually restart my computer, and it works fine again. Until it crashes again, and so on.

While this does not prevent me from using my laptop, it's quite annoying. I should also add that this is not a network issue, my phone and Ipad are working fine on the network, and it also happens when I'm at the university.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Some hints/leads...

- I might have changed the AdHoc11n setting of my Wi-Fi adapter to Disable based on an answer from another question (I'm not entirely sure what was the default setting).
- "Update Driver Software..." from Device Manager returns "The best driver software for your device is already installed", and I make sure to do this while I have a working internet connection.

[image: Device manager]

[image: AdHoc 11n setting]

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario your onboard WIFI chipset is defective. But your situation has so many variables that could play into it. I'll share my experience in case it might help. I had a similar issue (intermittent loss of Internet connectivity) and the problem turned out to be the Avast Internet Security software (version 17.3.2291, build 17.3.3443.0) on my Windows 10 laptop. I was able to pinpoint it to that by right-clicking on the Avast icon in the taskbar system tray and making the following cascading menu selection: "Avast shields control | Disable for 10 minutes". Lo and behold, in a couple of seconds my browsers could visit any webpage just fine and all Internet activity on my computer was restored. I'm looking into what Avast can do to help.